# Restarted Apache2 with Ubuntu for a Django Website, and CSS format no longer recognized. The site only shows basic HTML format. Any ideas to fix this?

Tags: python, django, apache2, materialize, restart

I had a functional Django Website that uses Materialize CSS apache2 and ubuntu. I made some small changes to the site (like changed text), then restarted the apache2 server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

After the restart, the website no longer showed the CSS format. The website is a basic html website now. I'm a quite new to building websites, so hoping there could be some ideas for what changed after the apache restart.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  There's little point in posting the command that restarts apache2; but to include your code and the changes.  It is invariably the code changes that killed the CSS.   If you have access to the server, take a look at the error logs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.